# Pushing content page down with drop down menu in Squarespace

Tags: css, portfolio, squarespace

I am trying to create a portfolio in order for my drop down menu to be pushed down when clicked on. But i would only like this to be applied to all my pages other than the home page. The navigations open over photos and it is quite hard to read, and I am not super familiar with code, so if anyone knows how to handle squarespace CSS editing, please let me know!

This is the page: www.emipun.com

Comment: You will need some JS logic for this. There is no css only solution.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of how to use JS to script a code in order to do that? Please let me know!

Comment: Most people here know how to do this. But you have to try yourself to do this and if you have problems we will help you. We don't provide ready to use code ( for copy/paste ).